# Can't open text file from Finder without extension even though execute flag is not set

Tags: finder, text, bbedit

Running Big Sur 11.3.1

I've got loads of text (UTF8) data files coming in from another Mac that I'd like to just double click or drag and drop to BBEdit or TextEdit. The files have no file extension and I'm not supposed to be changing the names unless I work from duplicates. The files can be opened from a file dialog but that's a bit tedious. When I drop on BBEdit I get messages that say the file cannot be opened because the developer is unknown and "macos cannot verify that this app is free from malware". That's an absurd message for a text file. Any thoughts on fixing this? (already tried chmod -x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I drop on BBEdit I get messages that say the file cannot be opened because the developer is unknown and “macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware”. That’s an absurd message for a text file. Any thoughts on fixing this?

You’re right, it is an absurd message, and unfortunately, it can happen with any file that you’ve downloaded from the Internet. It doesn’t have to have the executable ‘bit’ set.

The ‘fix’ for this would have to come from Apple.

However, in the meantime, the only thing you can do is remove the Quarantine flag:

`xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine '/the path/to/The File'`

For more information about this bug, see:

[Serious flaw in macOS: quarantine can stop you from opening documents – The Eclectic Light Company](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/05/03/serious-flaw-in-macos-quarantine-can-stop-you-from-opening-documents/)

Answer (score -1):

To open files from unknown developers you should enable the settings for this .

1. Open the file and see the unknown developer message and click ok .
2. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click General.
3. You can grant an exception for a blocked app by clicking the “Open Anyway” button in the General pane. This button is available for about an hour after you try to open the app.

If this didn't work , download [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) on your mac and open it then drag the text file into vscode .

Comment: Unfortunately, while this does work it only works for one file at a time so isn't super helpful in my situation. I hadn't tried that method before because the file isn't an app.